# Moving child div above another child div in each parent div

Tags: jquery

Using :contains(), I'm trying to target specific child divs within each parent div, and move it above (insertBefore) all other child divs.

```
<div class="roomRateRoomType">
    <div class="rateListing roomsView">
        <div class="rateTypeLineItems">

            <!-- Non-Best Flex Rate -->
            <div class="regularRates roomsView"> <span>Advance Saver Rate & Deals</span>

                <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>

            <!-- Best Flexible Rate -->
            <div class="regularRates roomsView">
                <div class="upsellHeader"> <span class="groupHeader">Best Flexible Rate &amp; Deals</span>

                    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rateListing roomsView">
        <div class="rateTypeLineItems">

            <!-- Non-Best Flex Rate -->
            <div class="regularRates roomsView"> <span>Some Other Advance Saver Rate & Deals</span>

                <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>

            <!-- Best Flexible Rate -->
            <div class="regularRates roomsView">
                <div class="upsellHeader"> <span class="groupHeader">Best Flexible Rate &amp; Deals</span>

                    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rateListing roomsView">
        <div class="rateTypeLineItems">

            <!-- Non-Best Flex Rate -->
            <div class="regularRates roomsView"> <span>And One More Advance Saver Rate & Deals</span>

                <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>

            <!-- Best Flexible Rate -->
            <div class="regularRates roomsView">
                <div class="upsellHeader"> <span class="groupHeader">Best Flexible Rate &amp; Deals</span>

                    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
<!-- */ END .roomRateRoomType -->

//move each Best Flex div above all siblings
$('.regularRates.roomsView').each(function() {
    $('.regularRates.roomsView:contains("Best Flexible Rate")').insertBefore('.regularRates.roomsView:eq(0)');
});
```

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkmills1/7e45N/5/). I understand why my target children are moved to the top of the **first** parent. How do I get my script to keep **each** child within it's relative parent?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.rateTypeLineItems').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.regularRates.roomsView:contains("Best Flexible Rate")').prependTo(this);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7e45N/6/)**

Comment: By the way, I took a slightly different approach by targeting a value attribute synonymous with the children in question.


`$('.rateTypeLineItems').each(function() {    $(this).find('.regularRates.roomsView').has(':input[value="IGCOR"]').prependTo(this);
});`